# Android: Managing a Service from a Widget

Tags: android, service, widget, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I'm sure this is an easy answer, but it's driving me crazy and I'm hoping someone can just put me out of my misery.

I have an android activity, widget and service. The service runs sound in the background, either for a set amount of time or continuously. Because I want the sound to run until stop is hit, I don't have a stopSelf() method in the service. This was all fine and dandy with the activity because I had it startService on play, and stopService on stop. Now I want to throw a widget in this latest update. So here's where I'm stuck. Because it's a broadcast receiver, I'm very limited in what it can do. I can call context.stopService, but I only want to stop the service when the button is pressed. I can only find a way to set an onClickListener with a pendingIntent.

In my service's onStartCommand() method, I read the "loops" extra from the incoming intent. So I tried just passing in a value of zero, but for some reason it doesn't seem to read it. I know the onStartCommand() is being called in the service because the music is playing, but regardless of what extra I throw on the intent, it doesn't seem to read it and I have no idea why. So my question is, what is the best strategy to use to stop a service from a widget's button? I'm hoping it's an easy answer, otherwise I guess I could create a new activity or broadcast receiver to handle the button click, but that seems so unnecessary. Any advice would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PendingIntent` you pass to the button in the Widget should be able to send Intent extras to the service like any other Intent: you should be able to detect that Intent in `onStartCommand` and then tell the Service to stop the sound and stop itself. Hard to tell what else you might be doing wrong without some code.

Comment: I figured it out... finally. I didn't have my pending intents properly flagged, so the extras weren't updating. Thanks for the quick response though. :)